# MeteorJS Mongo connection timed out

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-up

I have a MeteorJS app that is not connecting to Mongo. It's been deployed using meteor deploy but for some reason it times out when trying to connect to the database :S I can still access the mongo database using meteor mongo  and all of the data is present!

I am using Meteor 0.9.3.1 and here are my packages:

```
standard-app-packages
insecure
underscore
arunoda:npm@0.2.6
mrt:bootstrap-3
http
iron:router
mrt:q@0.9.7
mrt:moment@2.8.1
mrt:twilio-meteor
email
```

Here are the logs from meteor logs :

```
[Thu Oct 16 2014 17:39:25 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO Exception in setInterval callback: MongoError: connection to [production-db-a3.meteor.io:27017] timed out
    at Object.Future.wait (/meteor/dev_bundles/0.3.55/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:326:15)
    at _.extend._nextObject (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:858)
    at _.extend.forEach (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:892)
    at _.extend.map (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:902)
    at _.extend.fetch (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:926)
    at Cursor.(anonymous function) [as fetch] (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:741)
    at Object.residentModel.getActiveResidents (app/shared/collections/residents.js:43:40)
    at Object._.extend._run (app/server/services/deviceService/sensorChangeWatchdog.js:6:39)
    at app/lib/watchdogFactory.js:7:12
    at _.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56)
    - - - - -
    at Object.toError (/meteor/containers/450809a5-5a17-5e6e-8233-85e6ad895366/bundle/programs/server/npm/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/utils.js:110:11)
    at commandHandler (/meteor/containers/450809a5-5a17-5e6e-8233-85e6ad895366/bundle/programs/server/npm/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:679:63)
    at null.<anonymous> (/meteor/containers/450809a5-5a17-5e6e-8233-85e6ad895366/bundle/programs/server/npm/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1843:9)
    at g (events.js:180:16)
    at emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Base.__executeAllServerSpecificErrorCallbacks (/meteor/containers/450809a5-5a17-5e6e-8233-85e6ad895366/bundle/programs/server/npm/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:365:29)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/meteor/containers/450809a5-5a17-5e6e-8233-85e6ad895366/bundle/programs/server/npm/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/repl_set/ha.js:445:10)
    at Server.g (events.js:180:16)
    at Server.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at null.<anonymous> (/meteor/containers/450809a5-5a17-5e6e-8233-85e6ad895366/bundle/programs/server/npm/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:501:88)
[Thu Oct 16 2014 17:41:05 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS running -> killed
[Thu Oct 16 2014 17:41:05 GMT+0000 (UTC)] NOTICE Starting application on port 19159
[Thu Oct 16 2014 17:41:05 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS killed -> starting
[Thu Oct 16 2014 17:41:06 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS starting -> running
[Thu Oct 16 2014 17:41:07 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO init
```

Comment: how do you launch meteor? It looks like you have set the MONGO_URL environment variable.

Comment: I didn't explicitly set MONGO_URL. I just launched meteor with the default mongo settings

Comment: this looks weird, because by default meteor will create a mongo instance on localhost:3002 (or -p parameter +2). Your app is trying to connect to production-db-a3.meteor.io:27017 according to the logs. Where did that come from?

Comment: My guess is that hosted meteor has multiple production-db-{letter}{number}.meteor.io databases that uses. The issue has since resolved itself, it may have been some type of load spike :S